# Instaloader not providing complete list of followers when scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, instaloader

I am currently using instaloader for scraping followers on Instagram, but it seems that I am not getting the full list of followers as expected. I want to scrape all the followers of a particular account, but my current code doesn't seem to accomplish that.

Here's my code:

```
    # Get instance
    import instaloader

    L = instaloader.Instaloader()
    r = "username to scrape"

    # Login or load session
    username = "username"
    password = r'password'
    L.login(username, password)  # (login)

    # Obtain profile metadata
    profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, r)

    # Print list of followees
    follow_list = []
    count = 0
    for followee in profile.get_followers():
        follow_list.append(followee.username)
        file = open("prada_followers.txt", "a+")
    file.write(follow_list[count])
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    count = count + 1
```

Can someone please help me understand why I might not be getting the complete list of followers? Is there something wrong with my code, or is there a limitation with the instaloader library?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

One thing i did notice is that you're opening and closing the file inside the loop, which is inefficient, i would instead open the file once outside the loop and write all usernames, then close it after the loop instead.